# CakePHP 3 Routing: Scopes in prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0, prefix

I want to create this kind of architecture:

```
* Controllers
    * Tracking
        * Instagram
        * Twitter
    * Export
        * Instagram
        * Twitter
```

For example, I wanted to create the route `/tracking/instagram/create`
In **routes.php**, i added:

```
Router::prefix('tracking', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    \Router::scope('/instagram', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->connect('/create', ['controller' => 'Instagram', 'action' => 'create']);
    });
});
```

And I created the file **src\Controller\Tracking\InstagramController.php** with the namespace `App\Controller\Tracking` and the public function *create()*

Unfortunately I still have an :

> Error: A route matching "/tracking/instagram/create" could not be
>   found.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you try just put this?

```
Router::prefix('tracking', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*',[], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);

});
```

Comment: Oh it's that easy! Thank you